# how to make div with auto height overflow?

Tags: html, css

I got stuck. I have a wrapping div on my page with height set to some value. In this div, I have another div with set height (the yellow one). Under it, there is a blue div, which height automatically grows with the content. I want that div to have a scrollbar when the content exceeds all available height.

[image: question illustration]

here is an example you can play with:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #888891;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #FEEC63;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #63A4FE;
  overflow: hidden; /* why is that not hiding the excess text? */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  Hi there!
  </div>
  <div class="body">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/674w4a09/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> In order for the `overflow` property to have an effect, the block
>   level container must either have a bounding height (`height` or
>   `max-height`) or have `white-space` set to `nowrap`.

However, when you switch from a *block formatting context* to a *flex formatting context*, the requirement above doesn't apply and you can keep things simple:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #888891;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #FEEC63;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.body {
  overflow: hidden; /* switch to 'auto' for scrollbar */
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #63A4FE;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Hi there!</div>
  <div class="body">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG thank you! This took me so much time. I even believed that this is impossible

Answer (score 3):

add `height: calc(100% - 50px);` to .body and it will work

the overflow didn't working on **div.body** because the height wasn't fixed

and to make it fit the rest of the **container** you use `calc` to substruct the height of the **header** plus 10px of the `margin-bottom`

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/674w4a09/2/)

Answer (score 1):

add `height: calc(100% - 50px)` to .body

50px = 40px (of header height) + 10px (of header bottom margin)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <style>
                   .container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #888891;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #FEEC63;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #63A4FE;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}

                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="header">
                        Hi there!
                    </div>
                    <div class="body">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: tried in jsfiddle right now, not working (at least for me, chrome v56), see yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/4d5u4Leu/